# View many trees in subplot

Tags: matlab, tree, treeview, decision-tree, subplot

Does anyone have experience with viewing multiple decision trees simultaneously (side by side)? So basically is there a way to use [`view`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationtree.view.html) in conjunction with `subplot`?

The trees I want to view were create using `classregtree`.

I tried using [this method](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101806-how-can-i-insert-my-matlab-figure-fig-files-into-multiple-subplots) but it errors